# Error parsing JSON string with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm using Swift to parse JSON strings. This is the code:

```
var jsonStr = "..." // JSON string
var data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var error: NSError?
var array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as [AnyObject]
```

And this code works almost all the time. But today I tried to parse a new string input but it crashed my app in the last line. I couldn't even see the error message in the "error" variable... It crashed before that variable as updated with the error info.

The JSON string that I'm trying to parse is here: http://pastebin.com/wf6jtNhf

I'm confident that my JSON string is valid for two reasons:

- I validated the input using jsonlint.com
- I created a Objective-C version of the code above and it successfully parsed the same input

Can anybody see a reason why I can't parse this string or should I assume that the NSJSONSerialization class is bugged in Swift? I'm using Xcode Beta 3.

**Edit 1:**

Apparently there is a lot of UTF-16 characters in my string (emoji characters). Is there a key to parse the string keeping those characters? I tried `NSUTF16StringEncoding` the code below, but it didn't work:

```
var data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)
```

**Edit 2:**

I posted this same question in the Apple Developer forum and apparently there is indeed a bug in the Swift version of `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()` when there are emoji characters in the data. I hope this gets fixed in the final version.

Also, changing my variable from `[AnyObject]` to `as? Dictionary`, as some suggested below, didn't crash my app anymore.

Comment: Has anyone realized that over half the swift questions are about parsing JSON or XML?

Comment: In this case, it looks like your JSON will return a Dictionary and not an array.

Comment: @JackWu It's an array of [AnyObject] so it won't matter. I parsed similarly complex JSONs before with [AnyObject] and it worked fine, I don't think this is the problem. Also, my Objective-C version of the code above is sending the result to a NSArray and it worked as well. Thanks for the quick response, though.

Comment: Try calling `NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject` on it, is it returning true?

Comment: Also, it does matter in Swift, which is strongly typed. Your JSON's top level object is not an array. `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` returns a **Foundation Object** which in this case looks like a Dictionary. Try casting it to a dictionary and see if it still crashes

Comment: @JackWu It still crashes when I use a Dictionary. Also _NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject_ returns invalid, but I wonder why the Objective-C version of the code says it's valid...

Comment: It looks like the troublesome part is UTF-16 code points in plane 1, i.e.: emoji. Given this is JSON these code points should be in UTF-8.

Comment: @Zaph You are right. Sky also discovered the problem in his answer below. Strangely the Objective-C version of NSJSONSerialization can handle emoji because, as I said before, it parses the same string successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the past bin there are a good number of utf-16 characters interspersed in the JSON, that really is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing this on my computer, you're crashing because you're casting `as [AnyObject]`, and you're getting a nil result back out. If you change that to `as? [AnyObject]` then it will allow the return value to be nullable and you'll then be able to print the error.

As for the reason it's failing to parse, I'm not quite sure yet. The culprit seems to be the following chunk, not sure why it's invalid, perhaps some of the UTF is giving the parsing code problems.

```
"id": "@babiminkah",
               "nome": "B\u00E1rbara Santos",
               "imagem": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/490247572175327233/w4dXqfPm_bigger.jpeg",
               "texto": "amanh\u00E3 tem b\u00F3 do catarina..... na friends \uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02\uD83D\uDE02\uDE02",
               "horario": "2014-07-18 17:43:04"
               }
```

Edit1: Ripping out more pieces of that chunk, it is the `texto` field's value that's causing the problem. If you remove all of the value after and including `\uD83D` it will work. These unicode values seem to be the problem.

Edit2: According to this, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d83d/index.htm , `D83D` is not a valid unicode character. It seems likely some of the subsequent ones are not either.

Comment: Thanks, Sky! I using `as? [AnyObject]` now as you suggested and it's not crashing my app anymore, but the `error` is still nil. Anyway, you seem to be right about the unicode characters but I wonder why the Objective-C version of the code parses the JSON without a single problem...

Comment: You are the best. I just found out that D83D is a stupid emoji character... I'll try to remove that from the string before I parse the JSON. The interesting part is, as I said before, the Objective-C version of NSJSONSerialization can parse that string... apparently the Swift version can't do that yet. Thanks again!

Comment: \uD83D is the first hall of a surrogate  pair that encode a plane 1 character, the pair are: \uD83D\uDE02 which encodes . But then there is an extra \uDE02 after each pair so the encoding is incorrect. See [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Code points U+010000 to U+10FFFF. Unicode is a 21 bit encoding but until recently with the addition of emoji all the character could be encoded in 16 bits.

Comment: You really need to create a new question. The main thing I want to see is the actual data as a hex dump. An NSLog of the NSData would work. I would use Charles Proxy to see the raw hex data coming back from the server.